# How to pass/access a double pointer to/from a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, struct, double-pointer

A 10x10 matrix is created as follows:

```
double **c = (double **)pvPortMalloc(ROW * sizeof(double*));
for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    c[i] = (double *)pvPortMalloc(COL * sizeof(double));
```

I would like to pass `double **c` to a `struct`:

```
struct AMessage {
    char cMessageID;
    double (**doublePtr);
} xMessage;
```

At the end I want to access the struct and print the matrix on a screen, however, I am unsure how I should go about this using double pointers...

Comment: did you try `xMessage.doublePtr = c;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in direct answer to your question, if you define a matrix in that way and want to store its pointer in a struct, you can do it via a direct assignent. Carrying on from your example, you could make the `doublePointer` member of a `struct AMessage` point to the memory you've allocated at `c` simply via something like this:

```
struct AMessage am;
am.doublePtr = c;
```

But if you're wanting to create a matrix, where every row is guaranteed to have the same number of elements as any other row a better fit for representing this is a 2D array, rather than an array of pointers to other arrays.

A 2D array in C can be declared like so:

```
double matrix[ROW][COL];
```

this declares a variable called `matrix`, with `ROW` rows and `COL` columns.

There is nothing to stop you including this definition straight in the definition of your `struct`, making the definition of your struct like this:

```
struct AMessage
{
     char MessageId;
     double matrix[ROW][COL];
};
```

(Thanks to chqrlie for suggesting this)

If you definitely want a pointer to a 2D array to be in your `struct` (for example, you might want to have one large array referenced by two of your `struct`s) you need to know that a 2D array in C is really a 1D array, only addressed in a certain way.

You can dynamically allocate the memory to be used for the matrix with one call to malloc:

```
double *c = malloc(ROW * COL * sizeof(*c));
```

One option for accessing element the element in column `j`, row `i` is:

```
double a = c[ROW * j + i];
```

but this is obviously a bit clunky, really, it is more convenient to access element `i`, `j` by something like this:

```
double a = d[j][i];
```

To define the pointer `d` that we can dereference like this we need to think of what type `d[j]` is. It is not, as many think a `double *`, rather it is a pointer to an array of `ROW` `double`s. In C syntax you would declare `d` like so:

```
double (*d)[ROW];
```

Finally resolving your question, I would define your struct like this:

```
struct AMessage 
{
     char MessageId;
     double (*matrix)[ROW];
}
```

Assigning to this `struct` would look something like this:

```
struct AMessage am;
am.matrix = malloc(ROW * COL * sizeof(*am.matrix));
am.matrix[j][i] = 42; // Assigns 42 to row j, column i
```

Comment: You could also document that the `matrix` member of the structure can be defined as `double matrix[ROW][COL];` and used directly with the same syntax.

Comment: That's a good idea, and probably the nicest way of doing it in most cases. I've put it in, thanks!

Comment: Also give the direct answer to the OPs question: storing `c` to the struct is simply defining the member as `double **matrix;` and a simple pointer assignment does the job.  3 different ways to handle 2 dimensional matrices.

Comment: Yes I suppose I should, I guess I was letting my personal bias against this method show. It seems like an unnecessarily complicated series of mallocs and frees and I feel like it's only worthwhile doing when you have a ragged 2d array.

Comment: @chqrlie This is what I was thinking about. However, can I then simply do `AMessage.matrix = c` ? I am unsure how I should then use the matrix pointer in a `printf`

Comment: @BartasAbaravičius: yes you can, if the structure member is defined as `double**matrix;`

Comment: if you do that you access elements of `matrix` in much the same way as as a normal 2d array, i.e. `printf("%d\n", am.matrix[j][i]);` would print column `i` row `j` of the matrix. But it's important to realise how this array of pointers to arrays is different to a 2d array in terms of how it's laid out in memory